# Why is useParams returning undefined even with the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I read every question and answer and my problem is not gone.

I'm trying to access `http://localhost:3000/1`, and the `useParams` should receive `1` to fetch data from an API, but I'm receiving `undefined`.

In `Component.tsx`, I'm using `console.log` to receive the `useParams`, but I'm getting `undefined`. All related files are posted as I'm using `BrowserRouter` correctly and other related React Router imports.

What is wrong with my code? Why am I not getting the correct params?

Component.tsx:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { CharacterSchema, PageSchema } from "../interfaces/characterInterfaces";
import { IGetAllCharacters } from "../interfaces/contextInterfaces";
import { IChildren } from "../interfaces/reactInterfaces";
import api from "../services/api";

export const GetAllCharactersContext = createContext<IGetAllCharacters>({} as IGetAllCharacters);

export const GetAllCharactersInfo = ({ children }: IChildren) => {
  const [charactersList, setCharactersList] = useState<CharacterSchema[]>([]);

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const { page } = useParams();
  console.log(page);

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get(`/characters?page=${page}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setCharactersList(res.data.data);
        window.localStorage.setItem("lastPage", String(page));
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [page]);

  const nextPage = () => {
    navigate(`/2`);
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    navigate(`/1`);
  };

  return (
    <GetAllCharactersContext.Provider value={{ charactersList, nextPage, prevPage }}>
      {children}
    </GetAllCharactersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

AllRoutes.tsx:

```
const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/1" />} />
      <Route path="/:page" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default AllRoutes;
```

index.tsx:

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    import App from "./App";
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    import Providers from "./contexts/Providers";
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Providers>
            <App />
          </Providers>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this `<Route path="/:page" element={<Home />} />` will let you consume `page` with `useParams` only in `Home`, the component rendered by `Route` for this specific url.

A way to accomplish what you want is to move the fetching part inside `Home`. To do so, export as part of the context a function that fetches and updates the state:

```js
// ⚠️ Import what's needed
export const GetAllCharactersContext = createContext<IGetAllCharacters>({} as IGetAllCharacters);
export const GetAllCharactersInfo = ({ children }: IChildren) => {
  const [charactersList, setCharactersList] = useState<CharacterSchema[]>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const fetchCharactersList = useCallback((page) => {
    api
      .get(`/characters?page=${page}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setCharactersList(res.data.data);
        window.localStorage.setItem("lastPage", String(page));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);


  const nextPage = () => {
    navigate(`/2`);
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    navigate(`/1`);
  };

  return (
    <GetAllCharactersContext.Provider value={{ charactersList, fetchCharactersList, nextPage, prevPage }}>
      {children}
    </GetAllCharactersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And move that `useEffect` you had in the provider inside `Home`. Something like this:

```js
// ⚠️ Import what's needed
export default function Home() {
  const { fetchCharactersList, charactersList } = useContext(GetAllCharactersInfo);
  const { page } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!page) return;
    fetchCharactersList(page);
  }, [page]);

  // render data
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this myself. `useParams` needs to be used inside the `<Route>` where  the param is specified. It doesn't just pull them from the url. If you want to keep the structure the same I would suggest exposing a page setter from your context and setting it inside one of the components that can access the hook.

Alternatively you could use `useSearchParams` which actually takes data from the url search params itself, but you wouldn't be able to have it on the url then.